# What is causing null file names in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Some of my projects are unable to load files correctly. In the Solution Explorer, they have null filenames. I can still compile and work normally, but I cannot open them from this view. It says, "Cannot open file."

[image: Solution Explorer]

If I expand the view using Show All Files, I can see they are present but considered Excluded from the project. It's like they are both included and excluded simultaneously. Re-including them doesn't work.

[image: Showing All Files]

The project and filter files do not appear to be corrupt. I've even edited them manually to no avail. Here is the snippet from the VCXPROJ file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="JsonTest.cpp" />
  <ClCompile Include="NumberTest.cpp" />
  <ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
    <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
  </ClCompile>
  <ClCompile Include="StringArrayTest.cpp" />
  <ClCompile Include="StringTest.cpp" />
  <ClCompile Include="WStringArrayTest.cpp" />
  <ClCompile Include="WStringTest.cpp" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Here's a similarly relevant snippet of the .filters file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
    <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
  </ClCompile>
  <ClCompile Include="SrpString.cpp">
    <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
  </ClCompile>
  <ClCompile Include="SrpJson.cpp">
    <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
  </ClCompile>
  <ClCompile Include="SrpNumber.cpp">
    <Filter>Source Files</Filter>
  </ClCompile>
  <ClCompile Include="decNumber\decQuad.c">
    <Filter>DecNumber</Filter>
  </ClCompile>
</ItemGroup>
```

I've tried many things to fix this, none of which have been successful.

1. Run Visual Studio 2017 as Administrator
2. Removing and re-adding the files
3. Recreating the solution from scratch
4. Re-forcing all files in the folder to be not read only
5. Checking permission on all files: I do have full permissions

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `.vcxproj.filters` look like?

Comment: It looks equally valid. I'll include a relevant snippet. As I've said, I tried to edit and even replace it entirely to no avail.

Comment: if you include the Files into another Project, what happend then? evtl are the Files itselfs corrupt or damaged.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seemed to be related to a corruption of some type in the .vs sub-folder. Since I'm not using Visual Studio's built-in source control, I simply deleted that folder and reloaded the solution. Now everything is back to normal.

The clue was this: after manually deleting one of the null files (editing .vsproj directly, and deleting the files from the solution folder), I tried to use the Class wizard to re-add the class afresh. Yet, Visual studio insisted the class already existed, despite no mention of it in any source whatsoever. It seems a reference was being maintained invisibly via source control. I can't believe I didn't consider the .vs prior to this.

At any rate, I hope this helps someone else in the future.